# Re attack after “noping” a chain of attacks

Tags: exploding-kittens

In a game of Exploding Kittens, what happens when a chain of attack cards is followed by a Nope card, and the previous person attacks again?

For example:

- Player A plays an Attack card
- Player B plays an Attack card
- Player C plays an Attack card
- Player D plays a Nope card
- Player C plays an Attack card

What happens exactly? It re starts with only 2 turns, or 6 turns for player D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, a Nope card cancels only a single card (or one action with multiple cards in the case of a special combo) so player D will play 6 turns.

From [the rules](https://explodingkittens.com/how-to-play/exploding-kittens):

> Stop any action except for an Exploding Kitten or a Defuse Card. Imagine that any card beneath a Nope Card never existed.
>
> You can play a Nope Card **at any time before an action has begun, even if it’s not your turn**. Any cards that have been noped are lost. Leave them in the Discard Pile. You can even play a Nope on a SPECIAL COMBO